# How do i check if a method belongs to built in or user defined class easily in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have forked a GitHub android project and it is tiresome to find if a method belongs to  built-in class or user-defined class manually. (I need to go back and forth every time if it belongs to user-defined class.) How do I check if a method is built-in or user-defined easily?( And i mean to ask how it can be viewed easily in android studio?)
For example: onCreate(Bundle bundle) method is defined already in android studio( appCompatActivity). Now if i define my own method (say) doFoo(). How do any other person trying to fork my project know if that has been defined by me and not in java library itself?

Comment: Define "built-in". Built into what? Java's runtime library? The github project? --- And, BTW, methods cannot be independently built-in, since they belong to a class, so you should really be asking if the class is built-in, and if the full name of the class starts with `java.`, then it belongs to the Java runtime library.

Comment: Andreas is correct: your question isn't clear. Beyond that: you know that any decent IDE gives you something like a type hierarchy where you can quickly identify which classes implement respectively overwrite a mezhod?

Comment: I think I can use Structure tab to view fields and methods in a class. But still how do i know if it belongs to user-defined class or other external class( in java library)?

Answer (score 0):

The word *built-in* you mean is from an external class right? and I am answering on this assumption.

You can find using the below

1. You can find the method signature/declaration/definition in the same file for a user defined method.
2. If method is not called with any reference or class name, then it is user defined method.

Comment: Yeah! i mean external class and not just any external class but that defined already in android studio( java library)??

Comment: OK, so my previous answer would help you I think.